# how call data from json like this with Retrofit library

Tags: android, json, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit

```
i tried this :
interface MYAPI {
 @GET("get-languages")
 fun getdata() : Call<List<Data.Language>>
 } 
this is my api service
```

{
"message": "success",
"data": {
"language": [ {"id": 5,
"name": "English",
"icon": "19638193-en.png"
},
{
"id": 6,"name": "turkish","icon": "19638199-tr.png"}
]
}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{

   "message":"success",

   "data":{

      "language":[]

   }

}
```

Share your response model but you will need the "data" attribute that is a language model.  If you use directly the language model then won´t works.

So a possible data could be:

```
data class LanguageResponse(val id: Int, val name: String, val icon: String)
data class LanguagesResponse(val language: List<LanguageResponse>)
data class DataLanguageResponse(val data: LanguagesResponse)
```

And your call:

```
interface MYAPI {
 @GET("get-languages")
 fun getdata() : Call<DataLanguageResponse>
}
```

Comment: your code is right

Answer (score 0):

**Solved..**

i add to AndroidManifest :

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: The Error was : "java.net.unknown service exception cleartext communication to not permitted by network security policy"

Comment: I believe this won't work when you do a prod build or after some api versions so check that once as well